# osm2po Java API documentation

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, osm2po

I would like to get started writing a custom TagResolver, and I'm fairly unexperienced in Java.
Is there a osm2po Java API reference somewhere for the 'Default' classes (DefaultJoinInterceptor, DefaultWayTagResolver...) listing the overridable methods and their function, or some examples?

I found the TrafficSignalsNodeTagResolver.java in the plugins directory and I was wontering if there was something similar for the WayTagResolvers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, when I started this project years ago, I only programmed it for myself. Hence I didn't care for i18n and an english JavaDoc. I can only offer a german version if you can translate it somehow.
Nevertheless, it's only JavaDoc (for the routing but not for the conversion part) and no Cookbook. Best practise is to follow this forum and ask questions. You may also ask questions via email. By the way, here is a nice link...

[How to extend OSM2PO with ferry durations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations)

Comment: Thanks for the link it's a good starting point. I will ask a question related to my specific needs in a new post. Thanks.