# Where can I find osm2po javadoc

Tags: routing, osm2po

I would like to build an offline routing engine to compute route distance between two coordinates. 
I found osm2po but I didn't found any sort of documentation. As far as i understood osm2po can be used as java library.
Where can I find it? 
Because I didn't found any way to use osm files to find a path.
There's others valid offline engines that I can use? Or there's some sort of input paramenters to use with osm2po to get the distance? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version 4.8.8 is shipped with a german JavaDoc (routing API only).
Please excuse that it's not in english but when I started this project, I never thought that it would become that popular one day.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [OSM2PO Quick Start](http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) and [How to extend OSM2PO with ferry durations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations) might be helpful for you.