# How to extract shape of each segment?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

osm2po library does a great job in creating the data required by pgRouting to calculate theshortest paths. But I need the shape (Geometry - LineString 4326) to be extracted when osm2po generates the sql file for postgresql out of the .osm file.

Is there anyway to do this? Or maybe external library?
 I want the shape to be `Geometry(LineString,4326)` to fit into my database.

Answer (score 1):

osm2po, the latest version supports this. With the version `osm2po 4.8.8` I have successfully extracted the road links and their shapes and managed to import this to postgresql!

Comment: What? U see me totally confused about this thread. Did I drink too much "Glühwein"? Hey M-T-A can you give me the key for things "my" program can do, I don't know?

Comment: Dear Carsten, it's such a pleasure talking to you. My total respect and appreciation to you and your work. All I needed is the shape of each road link (or each row produced by your library) which is exactly the 'geom_way' column produced by the latest version I used. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: ............. ;-)

Comment: And please keep the Glühwein for the Christmas, it will be more fun this way :D

Comment: Our "Weihnachtsmarkt" opened today ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change the default output format.
You'll have to modify the code (pgRoutingWriter.java) and create your own plugin.
The basic steps for writing a osm2po-plugin are explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations)

```
package de.cm.osm2po.converter;

import static de.cm.osm2po.misc.Utils.DF;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import de.cm.osm2po.Config;
import de.cm.osm2po.Version;
import de.cm.osm2po.logging.Log;
import de.cm.osm2po.misc.WkbUtils;
import de.cm.osm2po.model.Node;
import de.cm.osm2po.model.SegmentedWay;
import de.cm.osm2po.model.WaySegment;
import de.cm.osm2po.primitives.InStream;
import de.cm.osm2po.primitives.InStreamDisk;
import de.cm.osm2po.primitives.VarString;
import de.cm.osm2po.primitives.VarTypeDesk;

public class PgRoutingWriter implements PostProcessor {

    private static byte[] KOMMA = ",".getBytes();
    private static byte[] SEMIKOLON = ";".getBytes();
    private static byte[] NEWLINE = "\n".getBytes();

    private static final char SINGLEQUOTE = '\'';
    private static final char SINGLESLASH = '\\';
    private static final byte[] DOUBLEQUOTE = "\'\'".getBytes();
    private static final byte[] DOUBLESLASH = "\\\\".getBytes();
    private static final byte[] SQLNULL = "null".getBytes();

    private boolean asMultilineString;

    @Override
    public void run(Config config, int index) throws Exception {

        File dir = config.getWorkDir();
        String prefix = config.getPrefix();
        Log log = config.getLog();

        String key = "postp." + index + ".writeMultiLineStrings";
        this.asMultilineString = Boolean.valueOf(
                config.getProps().getProperty(key, "false"));

        String tableName = (prefix + "_2po_4pgr").toLowerCase(); // Postgres-Problem
        String fileName = prefix + "_2po_4pgr.sql";

        File waysInFile = new File(dir, Segmenter.SEGMENTS_FILENAME);
        if (!waysInFile.exists()) {
            log.error("File not found : " + waysInFile);
            return;
        }
        InStream inStream = new InStreamDisk(waysInFile);

        OutputStream os = null;
        File sqlOutFile = null;
        if (config.isPipeOut()) {
            os = System.out;
            log.info("Writing results to stdout");
        } else {
            sqlOutFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(sqlOutFile), 0x10000 /*64k*/);
            log.info("Creating sql file " + sqlOutFile.toString());
        }

        byte varType = inStream.readByte();
        if (varType != VarTypeDesk.typeIdOf(SegmentedWay.class)) 
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected VarType " + varType);

        String lineformat = this.asMultilineString ? "MULTILINESTRING" : "LINESTRING";
        os.write((""
            + "-- Created by  : " + Version.getName() + "\n"
            + "-- Version     : " + Version.getVersion() + "\n"
            + "-- Author (c)  : Carsten Moeller - info@osm2po.de\n"
            + "-- Date        : " + new Date().toString()
            + "\n\n"
            + "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName + ";"
            + "\n"
            + "-- SELECT DropGeometryTable('" + tableName + "');"
            + "\n\n"
            + "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "("
            + "id integer, osm_id bigint, "
            + "osm_name character varying, osm_meta character varying, "
            + "osm_source_id bigint, osm_target_id bigint, "
            + "clazz integer, flags integer, "
            + "source integer, target integer, "
            + "km double precision, kmh integer, "
            + "cost double precision, reverse_cost double precision, "
            + "x1 double precision, y1 double precision, "
            + "x2 double precision, y2 double precision"
            + ");\n"
            + "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('" + tableName + "', "
            + "'geom_way', 4326, '" + lineformat + "', 2);\n")
        .getBytes());

        byte[] INSERT = ("\nINSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES ").getBytes();

        SegmentedWay way = new SegmentedWay();
        long n = 0, g = 0;
        while (!inStream.isEof()) {
            way.readFromStream(inStream);

            long osm_id = way.getId();
            byte clazz = way.getClazz();
            int flags = way.getFlags();
            byte[] nameBytes = this.toUTF8QuotedSql(way.getName());
            byte[] metaBytes = this.toUTF8QuotedSql(way.getMeta());

            int kmh = way.getKmh(); if (kmh <= 0) kmh = 1;
            boolean isOneWay = way.isOneWay();

            for (int i = 0; i < way.getSegments().length; i++) {
                WaySegment waySegment = way.getSegments()[i];
                int id = waySegment.getId();
                int source = waySegment.getSourceId();
                int target = waySegment.getTargetId();
                Node n1 = waySegment.getNodes()[0];
                Node n2 = waySegment.getNodes()[waySegment.getNodes().length -1];
                long osmSourceId = n1.getId();
                long osmTargetId = n2.getId();
                float km = (float) waySegment.calcLengthKm();
                float cost = km / kmh;
                float reverse_cost = isOneWay ? 1000000f : cost;

                String geom_way = WkbUtils.latLons2LineWkbHex(
                        waySegment.getNodes(), this.asMultilineString);

                // Gruppenbildung macht SQL erwiesenermassen schneller und kuerzer.
                if (g == 25) {
                    os.write(SEMIKOLON);
                    os.write(NEWLINE);
                    g = 0;
                }
                if (++g == 1) os.write(INSERT); else os.write(KOMMA);
                os.write(NEWLINE);

                os.write(("(" + id + ", " + osm_id + ", ").getBytes());
                os.write(nameBytes);
                os.write(", ".getBytes());
                os.write(metaBytes);
                os.write((", "
                    + osmSourceId + ", " + osmTargetId + ", "
                    + clazz + ", " + flags + ", "
                    + source + ", " + target + ", "
                    + km + ", " + kmh + ", " + cost + ", " + reverse_cost + ", "
                    + n1.getLon() + ", " + n1.getLat() + ", "
                    + n2.getLon() + ", " + n2.getLat() + ", "
                    + "'" + geom_way + "'" + ")")
                    .getBytes());

                if (++n % 50000 == 0) log.progress(DF(n) + " Segments written.");
            }
        }
        // Rest schreiben.
        os.write(SEMIKOLON);
        os.write(NEWLINE);

        log.info(DF(n) + " Segments written.");

        os.write(("\n"   
            + "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_" + tableName + " PRIMARY KEY(id);\n"
            + "CREATE INDEX idx_" + tableName + "_source ON " + tableName + "(source);\n"
            + "CREATE INDEX idx_" + tableName + "_target ON " + tableName + "(target);\n"
            + "-- CREATE INDEX idx_" + tableName + "_osm_source_id ON " + tableName + "(osm_source_id);\n"
            + "-- CREATE INDEX idx_" + tableName + "_osm_target_id ON " + tableName + "(osm_target_id);\n"
            + "-- CREATE INDEX idx_" + tableName + "_geom_way  ON " + tableName
            + " USING GIST (geom_way GIST_GEOMETRY_OPS);\n")
            .getBytes());

        inStream.close();

        if (sqlOutFile != null) {
            os.close();
            log.info("commandline template:\n"
                    + "psql -U [username] -d [dbname] -q -f \""
                    + sqlOutFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
        }

    }    

    private byte[] toUTF8QuotedSql(VarString strToEscape) {
        if (null == strToEscape || strToEscape.length() == 0)
            return SQLNULL;
        return strToEscape // Caution! No Copy()
            .replaceAsciiByte(SINGLEQUOTE, DOUBLEQUOTE)
            .replaceAsciiByte(SINGLESLASH, DOUBLESLASH)
            .quote(SINGLEQUOTE).getUTF8Bytes();
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the question is more that you just want to have the shape of OSM boundary of Germany, right?

This you can get in multiple different ways:

- http://ags.misterboo.de/api/v2/?cmd=dl&id=51477 (GeoJSON)
- https://toolserver.org/~kolossos/openlayers/kml-on-ol-json3.php?lang=en&title=Germany (GeoJSON)

This you can convert using OGR/QGIS/... to shapefile and then import to your database.