# osm2po custom node tag resolver problem

Tags: osm2po

I try to implement a custom node tag resolver to make a railway stations exported with specific clazz value.

I used this article [How to extend OSM2PO with ferry durations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations) as manual.

Class compiled and jar for new tag resolver created successfully.

But when I run an export with command:

```
java -Xmx2g -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar -classpath osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar:osm2po-plugins/osm2po-plugins-5.1.0_custom.jar:de.cm.osm2po.Main cmd=c /PATH-TO-OSM-FILE
```

The result is unsupported major,minor version 51.0.

As I understand, osm2po-core-5.1.0.-signed.jar compiled with 1.7.0_55-b13 and I had generate a osm2po-plugins-5.1.0_custom.jar with 1.7 version as well.

Is anyone had same problem?

folder structure:

```
osm2po-5.1.0/
   osm2po-doc/
   osm2po-plugins/
      de/
          cm/
             osm2po/
                demos/
                   ...
                samples/
                   MyNodeTagResolver.java
          de/
             cm/
                osm2po/
                   samples/
                      MyNodeTagResolver.class
      osm2po-plugins-5.1.0_custom.jar
      osm2po-plugins-5.1.0.jar
      osm2po-demos-5.1.0.jar
      demos.txt
   osm2po-web/
   osm2po.config
   osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**osm2po** is compatible with (and build for) Java 1.6.
I think you'll have to use the compiler option `-target 1.6`
in order to be binary compatible.

The original doc says:
*The major version number will be ..., 50 for Java 6, and 51 for Java 7.*

Tip! Read this to make things easier:

[How to extend OSM2PO with ferry durations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations#answer-70229)

Comment: Compiling with 1.6 did the job. Inside "osm2po-plugins/de" directory command "javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -d . -classpath ../../osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed-jar cm/osm2po/samples/MyNodeTagResolver.java" throws a warning but next steps goes without problem. Thanks!