# Customize osm2po sql script

Tags: postgis, osm2po

I am using osm2po to populate a pgrouting-compatible table in a postgis enabled database.
I changed the table definition a little bit (unlogged table for faster inserts, added indexes on osm_id for faster lookups, clustered on way geometry for faster seeks, ...).
I now need to update this table with fresh data. Can I somehow tell osm2po to not include DDL statements to create the table ? 
Also, can the `INSERT` statements be changed to `COPY` for faster inserts ?

My current solution is to `tail -n +13 osm\osm_2po_4pgr.sql` to strip the first rows. It's OK, but not the best solution. 
As for the `COPY` statements, I have no solution yet (replacing in the file would not be worth the computing time I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it'll be faster but not readable anymore - hard to debug if errors occur. So I once decided to use the text approach.
Anyway, you can review the sources in the plugin's sources which are open and part of the downloaded zip. Look for PgRoutingWriter.java.
To get an idea of how to customize binary things in osm2po read this article here: [How to extend OSM2PO with ferry durations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-extend-osm2po-with-ferry-durations#answer-70229)

Comment: Thanks ! I was hoping for a simple configuration setting, but I knew I would probably have to dig into the sources.